# Is there any way to mask material input control?

Tags: angular, angular-material, masking

I want to mask material date control, for that I have tried two npm modules.
first, I used [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask) and got this Error:

> ERROR Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute

The Reason for the error is; ngx used ValueAccessor in their realization, but angular has a limitation -> we can use only one realization ValueAccessor. That's why ngx-mask doesn't work with material.[refre](https://github.com/JsDaddy/ngx-mask/issues/50)

The Second solution is [VanillaTextMask.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vanilla-text-mask) and I got some abnormal behavior:

> If you try a date like "06/11/1983" you will see the model value is "06/11/1983_",and if you type another number it will get appended. [refer](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/294)

so, can anyone offer some other solution for implementing masking for angular material input control?

Comment: you can use a directive like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816

Answer (score 2):

Try with [Text mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/), they have to [work with angular 2+](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme).
Example with stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gdqkir

Comment: I have use Text mask as you suggested: getting extra character at input when added textmask directive with matDatepicker ; also if I add ngModel with the same then get `More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute` error

Comment: but why do you want to use mask and the picker in the same time? it doesnt make sense. Use the datepicker only, you dont need to use mask because the value will be always a date

Comment: if is a mat-datepicker, you can use only material, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218343/angular-material-date-picker-format-locale/57219390#57219390