# I'm getting an error when I use "key" instead of "keyCode" with "KeyboardEvent" in angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive for an input field (textbox) such that it accepts only numbers and not alphabetical characters. 
**I have the following (only-numbers.directive.ts) file**:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: "[onlyNumbers]"
})
export class OnlyNumbersDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(e: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (
      // Allow: Delete, Backspace, Tab, Escape, Enter
      [46, 8, 9, 27, 13].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
      (e.keyCode === 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+A
      (e.keyCode === 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+C
      (e.keyCode === 86 && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+V
      (e.keyCode === 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) || // Allow: Ctrl+X
      (e.keyCode === 65 && e.metaKey === true) || // Cmd+A (Mac)
      (e.keyCode === 67 && e.metaKey === true) || // Cmd+C (Mac)
      (e.keyCode === 86 && e.metaKey === true) || // Cmd+V (Mac)
      (e.keyCode === 88 && e.metaKey === true) || // Cmd+X (Mac)
      (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39) // Home, End, Left, Right
    ) {
      return; // let it happen, don't do anything
    }
    // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
    if (
      (e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) &&
      (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }

}
```

The code above works fine but I knew that the "**keyCode**" is deprecated, so I try to use "**key**" instead but I got this errors:

[Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBT0a.png)

[This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and '65' have no overlap. (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25qor.png)

So my question is how do I fix it?
**Thanks in advance**

Comment: It's not a response, it's another aproach: some time along.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816

Comment: Looks like it's going to be very useful, Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this solution as Eliseo pointed out and it worked very well
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54462816/6663458

Thanks Eliseo