# How to make custom directive in Angular2+ for giving , between number?

Tags: angular, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive

How to make custom directive in Angular2+ for giving ,(comma) between numbers?
For example: 100000 should output 1,00,000
Note : [ , should be come from custom directive]

Comment: If you want only show in .html use Decimal Pipe:https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe, if you want to show in an `<input>` when blur, create a directive. In  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439134/input-matinput-angular-material-form-allow-3-decimal-points-on-input-but/62440233#62440233 you has a directive who pass three decimals to two decimals. Only change the function `transform` to set e.el the formatted number

Answer (score 0):

There is no point for custom directive. In order to achieve your use case.you can use  angular built in function get Locale number format to solve your problem

Reference :  https://angular.io/api/common/getLocaleNumberFormat