# Angular ngModelChange is late when updating NgModel

Tags: angular

I'm making a directive using angular 8 to do some processing and convert the text to uppercase. Simplified code below:

html:

```
<input class="form-control" id="label" name="label" required myDirective>
```

directive:

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class Mydirective {
  constructor(private control: NgControl) { }

  processInput(value: any) {
     // do some formatting
     return value.toUpperCase();
  }

  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  ngModelChange(value: any) {
     this.control.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.processInput(value));
  }
}
```

Right now, the view is updated correctly, however the model is late by one step. for example:
if input text shows 'AAAA' then `ng-reflect-model` will show 'AAAa'.

I have reproduced the error in stackblitz: [Error Reproduced in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vwtbj3)

Any idea where I am wrong?

Thanks before!

Comment: Could you create a StackBlitz demo?

Comment: Added @AndreiGătej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get it using

```
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  ngModelChange(event: any) {
    const item = event.target
    const value = item.value;
    const pos = item.selectionStart;
    this.control.control.setValue(this.processInput(value), { emit: false });
    item.selectionStart = item.selectionEnd = pos
  }
```

See that we use @HostListener input, to get the item, not only the value. This allow us position the cursor in his position after change the value

NOTE: To make a simple uppercase it's better use css text-transform:uppercase and, when we want to get the value use toUpperCase()

NOTE2: about mask see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816)

Answer (score 13):

### TLDR

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kv3g3f?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-directive.directive.ts).

#### my-directive.directive.ts

```js
/* ... */

ngOnInit () {
  const initialOnChange = (this.ngControl.valueAccessor as any).onChange;

  (this.ngControl.valueAccessor as any).onChange = (value) => initialOnChange(this.processInput(value));
}

/* ... */

@HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
ngModelChange(value: any) {
  this.ngControl.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.processInput(value));
}
```

---

### Detailed answer

Let's see why it didn't work initially.

Angular has *default value accessors* for certain elements, such as for `input type='text'`, `input type='checkbox'` etc...

A `ControlValueAccessor` is the *middleman* between the VIEW layer and the MODEL layer. When a user types into an input, the VIEW notifies the `ControlValueAccessor`, which has the job to inform the MODEL.

For instance, when the `input` event occurs, the `onChange` method of the `ControlValueAccessor` will be called. [Here's how](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L93-L101) `onChange` looks like **for every** `ControlValueAccessor`:

```js
function setUpViewChangePipeline(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  dir.valueAccessor!.registerOnChange((newValue: any) => {
    control._pendingValue = newValue;
    control._pendingChange = true;
    control._pendingDirty = true;

    if (control.updateOn === 'change') updateControl(control, dir);
  });
}
```

The magic happens in [`updateControl`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L112-L117):

```js
function updateControl(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  if (control._pendingDirty) control.markAsDirty();
  control.setValue(control._pendingValue, {emitModelToViewChange: false});
 
  // !
  dir.viewToModelUpdate(control._pendingValue);
  control._pendingChange = false;
}
```

`dir.viewToModelUpdate(control._pendingValue);` is what invokes the `ngModelChange` event in the custom directive. What this means is that the **model value** is the value from the input(in lowercase). And because `ControlValueAccessor.writeValue` **only** writes the value to the VIEW, there will be a *delay* between the VIEW's value and the MODEL's value.

It's worth mentioning that `FormControl.setValue(val)` will write `val` to **both** layers, VIEW and MODEL, but if we were to used this, there would be an **infinite loop**, since `setValue()` internally calls `viewToModelUpdate`(because the MODEL has to be updated), and `viewToModelUpdate` calls `setValue()`.

Let's have a look at a possible solution:

```js
ngOnInit () {
  const initialOnChange = (this.ngControl.valueAccessor as any).onChange;

  (this.ngControl.valueAccessor as any).onChange = (value) => initialOnChange(this.processInput(value));
}
```

With this approach, you're modifying your data at the VIEW layer, before it is sent to the `ControlValueAccessor`.

And we can be sure that `onChange` exists on every built-in `ControlValueAccessor`.

[image: search results]

If you are going to create a custom one, just make sure it has an `onChange` property. TypeScript can help you with that.

If you'd like to read more about internals of `@angular/forms`, I'd recommend having a look at [A thorough exploration of Angular Forms](https://indepth.dev/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms/).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation

***writeValue:** This method is called by the forms API to write to the view when programmatic changes from model to view are requested.*

Calling this method on the control will hence only update the view. To Update the model we can call **viewToModelUpdate(value: string)** on the NgModel class. This will update the model

```
constructor(private model: NgModel) { }
processInput(value: any) {
   // do some formatting
   return value.toUpperCase();
}

@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
ngModelChange(input: any) {
  const value = input.target.value
  this.model.valueAccessor.writeValue(this.processInput(value));
  this.model.viewToModelUpdate(this.processInput(value));
}
```

Below is a working solution on stackblitz [Working Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3xaxja)