# how can I make an input field only accept numbers when the input type is text?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Here's my input field with label as ID, I want this input field to only accept numbers without changing the type to number.

```html
<label for="id">ID:</label>
<input type="text" 
      class="form-control form-control-sm" 
      formControlName="idCardInput" 
      name="idCard" 
      id="idCard" 
      ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" />
```

Comment: it's a bit old but, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163661/i-want-to-restrict-input-type-text-only-alphanumeric-in-angular-9-globally/64167098#64167098

Comment: You can not prevent users from typing anything else than numbers in an input. For once the letter `E` is a valid number expression. Second, a User can always break it. That's why you should run a plausibility test and a validation and warn the user if the input is invalid.

Comment: ngx-mask is one viable option if you're willing to reach for a library option

Comment: @tacoshy, impossible is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, you can use this function whenever you want inside your particular project or website.

```js
function isNumberKey(event){
var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
return true;
}
```

```html
<input name="id" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"/>
```

Comment: the problem is when you make a copy + paste

Comment: @Eliseo It's easy man, everyone knows this!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment: you give a non Angular solution that not resolve the question, I only want to advertise about this.

Comment: @Eliseo Ohh sry I hv seen it now btw he has accepted the code... But how??????Btw I am new to stackoverflow so I will remember this for my next time...Thanks...

Comment: @Eliseo I figured that out during the testing process of the system.

Answer (score 0):

If validating is not enough, and you want to accept only numeric chars inside the input field:

You can either use a function to test the input value on change and then to replace it, either way you should use a regex:

1. `/^\d+$/`
2. `/^[0-9]*$/`

Both options are fine

Since you are using angular you can use the (change) event and to call a function that will adjust the form control's value which is bind to the input.

You can also do it on the input itself using the oninput event together with this.value

Comment: you should not just replace an input based on a regex. It makes up for poor UX and Accessibility. You should always warn a user instead!

Answer (score -1):

You need to create numbersOnly directive and then use it in your html. Use the following stackblitz link for reference:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numbers-only-directive?file=app%2Fapp.component.html