# Allow only alphabet in input Html - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to know how to only allow alphabet in an input, if a number or special character is entered in the input, ignore it, i work with Angular.

I work with reactive form but if I use pattern this just validates the field when submit is done, what I need is that for example if I press the number "1" in keyboard it simply does not show, when the key is pressed ignore everything that is not alphabet letter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816

Answer (score 4):

You can use input mask libraries like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask. Or You can do it yourself like this

```
this.form.controls["Your Control Name Here"].valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
    this.form.controls["Your Control Name Here"].setValue(value.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/, ""), { emitEvent: false });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to achieve is a validation check, enforcing input is not a very user-friendly approach, as user type and is unable to figure out what is wrong.
A better approach for validation should be a validation check and error with a proper explanation about what is wrong in typed input.
(if your request is required for other reason, then feel free to ignore my comment)

for validation -
you can use input pattern:
<input matInput type="text" [formControl]="your-control-name" pattern="[ a-zA-Z]*">

and as part of validation errors check you handle the pattern error:
<mat-error *ngIf="formHandlersList[i].hasError('pattern')">
Only alphabetic characters are allowed

the full block of html looks something like this -

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="standard" [style.width.px]="120">
   <input matInput type="text" [formControl]="your-control-name" pattern="[ a-zA-Z]*">
   <mat-error *ngIf="<your-form-control-object>.hasError('pattern')">
      Only alphabetic characters are allowed
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```