# How to convert a comma to dot automatically?

Tags: angular

When the user enters a comma in the INPUT, I would like the comma to be automatically transformed in a dot. Is it possible?

```
<label>Number </label>
<input type="number" maxlength="5" />
```

Here is a reproduction -> [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rmxxpt?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace comma with dot in a input Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435744/replace-comma-with-dot-in-a-input-javascript)

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN I was going to answer that xdd

Comment: @MD. RAKIB HASAN, Thanks for your help, the link is for javascript, I am using angular. I don't understand JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make something like this old [SO about mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816)

Create a directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[notdot]'
})
export class NotDotDirective {

  constructor(@Optional() @Host()private control:NgControl) {}
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  change($event) {

    const item = $event.target
    const value = item.value;
    const pos = item.selectionStart; //get the position of the cursor

    const matchValue = value.replace(/,/g, '.')
    if (matchValue!=value)
    {
      if (this.control)
        this.control.control.setValue(matchValue, { emit: false });

      item.value = matchValue;
      item.selectionStart = item.selectionEnd = pos; //recover the position
    }
  }
}
```

And use like

```
<input notdot maxlength="5"/>
```

NOTE You can use also with template driven forms or with ReactiveForms

```
<input notdot [(ngModel)]="variable" maxlength="5"/>

<input notdot [formControl]="control" maxlength="5"/>
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m9qczf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdot.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Using Angular Form Controls will automatically convert it to a correct number :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uewxfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Thank you but the comma appears in the input, I would like to replace the comma in the input with a dot, is it possible, please?

Comment: Why would you do that in the first place ?

Comment: it's just a convention.

Comment: Are you aware that this "convention" changes according to the country your app is running ?

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` [elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) of type number are used to let the user enter a number. They include built-in validation to reject non-numerical entries.

The user cann't input comma in the `INPUT`, so first you have to change input type as text. after that on `onkeyup` event you can replace the value like below:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/,/g, '.');"/>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hc3mn8?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: This makes each key down go to last position