# How to display a comma only in an input?

Tags: angular

In the input HTML, currently, the user can enter multiple commas, I would like to reduce the number of commas by `1`. I d'ont know how to make this?

For example: The user cannot enter `20......01` but only `20.01`

**app.component.html**

```
<input notdot maxlength="5" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  value
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, NotDotDirective],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**dot.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive,Injector,HostListener,Optional,Host } from '@angular/core';
import {NgControl} from '@angular/forms'
@Directive({
  selector: '[notdot]'
})
export class NotDotDirective {

  constructor(@Optional() @Host()private control:NgControl) {}
  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  change($event) {

    const item = $event.target
    const value = item.value;
    const pos = item.selectionStart; //get the position of the cursor

    const matchValue = value.replace(/,/g, '.')
    if (matchValue!=value)
    {
      if (this.control)
        this.control.control.setValue(matchValue, { emit: false });

      item.value = matchValue;
      item.selectionStart = item.selectionEnd = pos; //recover the position
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a reproduction -> [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m9qczf?file=src/app/dot.directive.ts). If you have a solution, I am really interested.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can't you just add `type="number"` to your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menier, then use a ["mask" directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816) (but you check againts `value.replace(/,/g, '.');` . Some like

```
regExpr = new RegExp('^([1-9]\\d*|0)(\\.)?\\d*$');

@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  change($event) {

    let item = $event.target
    let value = item.value;
    let pos = item.selectionStart;
    let matchvalue = value.replace(/,/g, '.');
    let noMatch: boolean = (value && !(this.regExpr.test(matchvalue)));
    if (noMatch) {
      item.selectionStart = item.selectionEnd = pos - 1;
      if (item.value.length < this._oldvalue.length && pos == 0)
        pos = 2;
      if (this.control)
        this.control.control.setValue(this._oldvalue, { emit: false });

      item.value = this._oldvalue;
      item.selectionStart = item.selectionEnd = pos - 1;
    }
    else
    {
      //we check here if matchValue!=value

      if (matchvalue!=value)
      {
        item.value = matchvalue;
        item.selectionStart = item.selectionEnd = pos;
      }

      this._oldvalue = matchvalue;

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

On your directive you can change line 20 with:

```
const matchValue = value.replace(/,/g, '.').replace(/\.\./, '.');
```

You are replacing comma with dots and if you insert more than one dot, it replaces the input with just only one

Comment: What if you insert the second dot in another part of the string? Like `1.2.3`?

Comment: @Octavian Mărculescu, you have right

Answer (score 0):

Here's another take , especially if it's only for display , I have in input that uses the value attribute (and ngModel) and the Angular currency pipe to manipulate the input-value using comma separators,

Also bonus , in mine I have the numeric keypad for mobile devices

```
 <input type="text"
   [(ngModel)]="amount" 
   name="amount"
   pattern="[0-9]*" 
   inputmode="numeric" 
   [value]="amount | currency : ' ' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'"
   oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'').replace(/^0/,'').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"
  >
```