I need an input for angular that does not accept any characters String only numbers
do you need a way to use an input that only accepts numeros, I already tried it in my project
type = "number", deixar por um caractter stering , usei o pattern="[0-9]+$"  and it doesn't work
    <input [(ngModel)] = "produto.descricao"  matInput formControlName="descricao" placeholder="Digite uma descricao" pattern="[0-9]+$"> não funciona

    <input [(ngModel)] = "produto.descricao"  matInput formControlName="descricao" placeholder="Digite uma descricao" type="number"> and it doesn't work


e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54460923/angular-2-restrict-input-field/54462816#54462816. BTW: NOT use in the same tag input ngModel and FormCntrolName. you should choose if you want to use Template driven forms or Reactive Forms. If you use reactiveForms use setValue or pathValue or when you create the formGroup to give value to the FormControl.
