# Configure moment custom date adapter

Tags: angular, momentjs

I have used moment date adapter. So the main issue which I'm facing is whenever I type date like 1/12/56 and after pressing tab it auto corrects to 2056 instead of 1956. And only it shows correct year whenever I type 69-99 and it changes to "19"

[image]

My custom date adapter code is:

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Optional } from "@angular/core";
import { MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from "@angular/material";
import { MomentDateAdapter } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
import { Moment } from "moment";
import * as moment from "moment";

@Injectable()
export class MomentUtcDateAdapter extends MomentDateAdapter {
    constructor(@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DATE_LOCALE) dateLocale: string) {
        super(dateLocale);
    }

    createDate(year: number, month: number, date: number): Moment {
        return moment({ year, month, date });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look to [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218343/angular-material-date-picker-format-locale/57219390#57219390)

You can change the parse function like

```
parse(value:string):any
   {
     let parts=value.replace(/\./g,'/').replace(/-/g,'/').split('/');
     let year=+parts[2]
     if (year<100) //if is less than 100
     {
       year=(year<56)?year+2000:year+1900 //sum 1900 or 2000 acording requeriment

     }
     if (parts.length==3)
      return new Date(year,(+parts[1])-1,+parts[0])

   }
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ro1wdw-t7ufgg?file=app/datepicker-formats-example.ts)

Comment: But a simple error I m getting after adding this parse function

" ERROR TypeError: date.clone is not a function"

Do you any idea how to fix this issue

Comment: In my stackblitz don't happens.. if you receive data.clone, check where you has write "date.clone", and make sure date is not null `if (date){ date.clone()}`